# Convert mysql timestamp to jpa entity java.util.Calendar field

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, calendar, timestamp

There's an entity class containing a Calendar field:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

   ...

   @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)    
   private Calendar lDate;

   ...

}
```

when I want to get hour, minute or second fields of the 'lDate' it returns 0:

```
...

myEntityObject.getlDate().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

...
```

but the related table record has different values.

I don't know waht's the problem :(

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: and myEntityObject.get1Date() returns WHAT?

Comment: It returns a date-only value such '2014-12-20 00:00:00'